# Unable to login to phpmyadmin ( mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002))

Tags: mysqli, phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost, wamp

I have been trying to install WordPress on my PC , to configure WordPress i have installed wamp local server. once i start server and open phpmyadmin i login directly with my username password but sometime it will logout autometically and give the following errors .

> 1.#2002 - An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full. — The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
>
> 2.mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full.

Comment: Please post textual errors and messages as text, not as screenshots.

Comment: That might not seem like a big deal, but now they're searchable by others that might have this same, unusual problem.

Comment: okey. please let me know how can i resolve this issue i tried reinstalling my wamp but it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: Can you connect to that MySQL instance using other tools like [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)? It's worth testing if this is a PHP problem or a MySQL problem.

Comment: okey. i will give it a try

Comment: the problem was with my wifi adapter which i was uisng to connect to  internet . when i connected my internet using Lan cable it worked fine form me thank you.